# Как можно почистить много html страниц?

Tags: html

Есть больше 30к html страниц, уважаемые стаковерфловцы подскажите пожалуйста каким инструментом можно это сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На скриншоте выделенный нужный текст который необходимо оставить. Все что не выделено нужно удалить. Буду рад любой мысли! Спасибо.

Comment: на питоне можно написать скрапер ( с помощью [Beautiful Soup](http://wiki.python.su/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8/BeautifulSoup) ) который будет вырезать соответсвующую часть находя ее по имени класса и сохранять в другу папку файл с тем же именем

Comment: я в таких случаях использую перл с его регулярками.

Comment: 25 строк кода на python получилось с помощью Beautiful Soup, спасибо!